# Saving an image file to the IIS Server - ASP.NET - GDI+ error, IIS LOCAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm not too experienced in ASP.NET, but this is what I am trying to achieve - and by the way it works lovely in IIS Express.

An image, delivered in a Byte[] by a WCF Service, is being rendered to a webpage every second or so. The very first image is being saved on the server in the folder "Thumbnails" off the application root (the page that does the saving is in the folder "RestrictedAccess" off the application root) . This works fine in IIS Express, but I'm having serious difficulties when it comes to running it from my local IIS Server.

My first problem is the saving of the image. When I attach to the IIS process, the folder it is trying to save the image in is not the folder I expect (i.e. wwwroot/MyWebsite/Thumbnails) but the PROJECT folder i.e "c:\development\MyWebSite\Thumbnails")

Secondly, when it attempts to save the image, I get a "general error occurred in GDI+". I'm pretty sure this is due to the path, but how do I get it to save in the correct (wwwroot..../thumbnails) folder?

Here's my source

```
               string imageStr = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])mimicImage);

                        imMimic.Src = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}{1}", imageStr, "");
                        lbServiceResponse.Text = String.Format("Service response : {0}", "OK");

                        //
                        // Update thumbnail ?
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mimicData.ThumbNail))
                        {
                            mimicData.ThumbNail = String.Format("../ThumbNails/Thumbnail_{0}.jpg", mimicData.ID);
                            string thumbNailFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\ThumbNails\") + string.Format("Thumbnail_{0}.jpg", mimicData.ID);
                            //
                            // Write image to disk
                            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(mimicImage))
                            {
                                // Bitmap object
                                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                                bmp.Save(thumbNailFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                                bmp.Dispose();
                            }
                            //
                            // Update service
                            _client.UpdateMimicThumbNail(MimicID, mimicData);
                        }
```

I've been struggling with this for best part of a day (I'm new to ASP.NET and the whole IIS stuff), so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

p.s. The Web App is running in its own application pool with ApplicationPoolidentity.

Comment: `mimicData.ThumbNail = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("/ThumbNails/Thumbnail_{0}.jpg", mimicData.ID));`
`string thumbNailFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("/ThumbNails/Thumbnail_{0}.jpg", mimicData.ID));` and set permissions to the root website folder for applicationpool identity

Comment: @VMV . Sorry doesn't work. Still puts the image in the project folder, not the one under IIS. And this is when running and visual studio is not even open! How does it do this?? I'm running the blasted thing from a browser, hosted in IIS and with VS not open yet it still deposits it into c:\dev..\MyApp\Thumbnails" WTF? And btw, I do not have an ApplicationPoolIdentity user

Comment: Ok, try to debug in IIS `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/")` - what value it return? BTW, AppPool user always exist, but he is in hidden group. Let's imagine, that your IIS apppool have name 'mylovelyserver'. Then, when you try to add user on "Security" tab on folder, just type 'IIS AppPool\mylovelyserver' and press button 'check name'. Also, check location field, it should contain machine name (not domain or active directory).

Comment: @VMV. This was still showing the development folder, so I double checked the IIS settings for the website. This was showing the physical path as my development folder(!) although I swear, this was previously showing the IIS folder and I NEVER would have set it to the development folder myself. Is this something VS would do in the background, if I were to change the project setting to IIS Express (which I have done at sometime when I was experiencing DB issues)?